# PHP function testing library to test PHP functions online

Tags: php, testing

I came across this cool little PHP function testing tool website today at http://php.fnlist.com/array/array_count_values

It claims to have over 200 PHP functions to test online.

Each functions has a page which has input fields for each function parameter.  You can then enter a string, array, date, or whatever is ask for and it will pass those input field values into the PHP function and show the result on the page.

It's a useful little tool for testing how certain functions work on different sets of data, etc...

I am building a Web Developer Toolbox app which takes all my most used and favorite web dev apps and tools and combines them into 1 single app.  Each tool in my app is going to be a "plugin" so that users can add/disable/create there own dev tools as needed in the app.

So I am wanting to have a plugin tool in my app with similar functionality as this website to allow the testing of PHP functions.

Does any open source projects exist that do this task already that anyone knows of?  Otherwise I am asking how to go about building such a tool.

For example if a function parameter expects an array to be passed in.  How can I ensure that the text input POSTed has a valid array or string or Date or whatever it is asking for?

Also any other related info that might be useful to build such a tool is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here https://github.com/Corveda/PHPSandbox

Demo of it: https://code.phpsandbox.org/

GitHub project: https://github.com/Corveda/PHPSandbox

Docs:  https://manual.phpsandbox.org/2.0/